# How to add date in SPSS Modeler?

Tags: spss-modeler

How to add months, weeks or year in SPSS Modeler. The date data is in  MMDDYYYY. If I want to add months by 5 , what I supposed to do in SPSS Modeler.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a derive node and the the query below:

**to_date((datetime_year(@TODAY))><'-'><(datetime_month(@TODAY)+5)><'-'>< (datetime_day(@TODAY)))**

The query above will add 5 months starting from today's date, but you can also use some date variable in the same query and it will work fine as well.

Hope to have been helpful!